# PHP/MYSQL Insert is doing nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form set up in HTML to pass values to PHP and put them in a MYSQL database. I just can't fathom why nothing is happening when I click the submit button. Previously it was saying 'failed' but now nothing. I have checked the values from the form - fine. I've checked the database connection - fine. I've checked the SQL statement - well, I can't see any errors.

This is my main HTML page

```
<p class="subtitle">Let me know what you think</p>
<form action="db_insert.php">
<input name="username" placeholder="Name">
<br>
<textarea name="comments" placeholder="Please type your comments here" 
cols=120 rows=5></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
<br>
<p id="commTitle">Comments</p>
<br>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

This is the PHP

```
<?php
include 'db_connection.php';

//create database connection 
$conn = OpenCon();
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO sitecomments(username, comment) VALUES(:username,:comment)';
$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt -> bindValue(':comment', $comment);
$q_result = $stmt -> execute();

if($q_result){
echo 'Comment Inserted Successfully';
}
else{
echo 'Failed';
}
```

db_connection.php looks like this (with credentials removed.

```
<?php

function OpenCon(){
    //pass the database details to variables
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "*****";
    $dbpass = "*****";
    $dbname = "*****";
    // combine host and db name in to single variable
    $dbhost = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
    //create PDO from database information
    $dbconn = new PDO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    return $dbconn;
}
?>
```

As I said, I've checked the database connection and all is fine so where on earth am I going wrong? My database has 3 fields but one is autoincremented so I haven't included it in the query. I tried the query in MyPHPAdmin and it passed ok.

Comment: It would help if you checked for errors in your code

Comment: Don't guess when the query fails. Instead, check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: You should check $stmt->errorInfo()

Comment: Also, not the issue but don't use `htmlspecialchars` here.

Comment: output the raw query that would get run, and then review it for problems / test it in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin.

Comment: try adding `if( !$stmt )exit('bad foo');` after the `$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);` to be sure the prepared statement is beimng created OK. And, more importantly add `method='POST'` to the form tag

Comment: FYI - it should be `<br />` not simply `<br>`

Comment: try var_dump($_POST); turn on error_reporting so you see notices and errors in your code, such as trying to use an array index that doesnt exist.

Comment: the default method for a form is `GET` - as the form has no `action` you will not be POSTing data but GETting

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that the input has name of "comments" rather than the $_POST variable you're accessing called comment:

`<textarea name="comments" placeholder="Please type your comments here" cols=120 rows=5></textarea>`

`$comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);`

Try changing that and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Even undefined it should insert an empty record.

Comment: Correct, unless the error occurs when running htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment'])

Comment: Glad to hear it @HarrySampson. If you have a chance, can you mark my answer as the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to handle errors within your code. In your current example if something goes wrong you will have a hard time finding out where the problem is.

You can try all of the following examples from the PHP Docs on [PDO error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) and [PDO::errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php):

---

#### Assert your connection is valid:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

#### Assert your SQL is valid

```
/* Provoke an error -- bogus SQL syntax */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('bogus sql');
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

As usual the error is a [pebcak](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PEBCAK) error, and you need to utilize proper debugging tools to find out where your mistakes are. Good luck!